# foreach not looping, am I referencing incorrectly?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following code in a background music player for a kiosk:-

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="true" loop="true"  >
<?php     
    $music = glob("./music/*");  // get all files in the music directory
    shuffle($music);
    foreach ($music as $song){         
        echo '<source src="'. $song . '" type="audio/ogg">';
    }

   ?>
</audio>
<?php var_dump($music); ?>
```

It is only writing a single source element, matching the first member of the (shuffled) array.

The debug dump lists the full array, so I figure I have something wrong either in my foreach expression or in the echo expression.

Comment: `var_dump($music);`
to check if it's array

Comment: Richard Grevers  chcek the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct you need to correct your `glob('<need some change here>')` it's just path problem otherwise code is perfect.

```
C:\wamp64\www\phpDiary\program\1.php:10:
array (size=5)
  0 => string '1 (2).jpg' (length=9)
  1 => string '2.php' (length=5)
  2 => string '1.php' (length=5)
  3 => string '1 (1).jpg' (length=9)
  4 => string '1 (3).jpg' (length=9)
```

**This is output of your code. i think its $music = glob("../music/*");**

> Double Dot to go backward in directory

replace your code with this.

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="true" loop="true" controls>
<?php
    $music = glob("../music/*");  // get all files in the music directory
    shuffle($music);
    foreach ($music as $song){
        // echo '<source src="'. $song . '" type="audio/ogg">';
        echo "<source src='".$song."' type='audio/ogg'>";
        // echo "hello";
    }
   ?>
</audio>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific - my array is correctly populated with all the track URLS - the directory specifier is correct as is. but only the first source tage is being written.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that the HTML5 Audio element has no means of specifying multiple sources to be played in sequence. Multiple source tags simply specify alternatives (to cover for incomplete browser support of formats), which I already knew.
What threw me off the track was that view source showed the computed source, showing the source tag only of the first successful source. The rest were visible via the Element Inspector.

So I need to use a javascript solution, such as the one at http://www.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/
That will be tomorrow's task :-) Thanks for your time.